# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity is dropping columns on the floor

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

first time, long time.

I'm running an import of a csv file that has 734 columns in Azure Data Factory Copy Activity. Data factory is not reading the last 9 columns and is populating with NULL. Even in the preview I can see that the columns have no values but the schema for those columns is detected. Is there a limit of columns in Copy to 725?

Comment: i uploaded a csv that only had 20 records in it and 'I'm still not seeing the last columns. I wish i could find some documentation on this. Surely someone else has run across this.

Comment: I've worked with CSVs with well over 1,000 columns, so that should not be the cause. I would start by checking the schemas of the datasets to make sure they references all the expected columns.

Comment: I think there's something from your csv file that has caused and might not be because of azure itself. Try to look for some special characters that could have potentially caused this

Answer (score 0):

As Joel said there is no restriction for 725 or so columns . I suggest

1. Go to the mapping tab and only pick 726th column ( if you have a header it will be easy or ADF will generate header like Prop_726( most probably) , copy the data to blob as sink , If the blob has the field , that means that you have a data type issue on the table .

Let me know how its goes , if you are still facing the issue , please share some dummy data for 726th column .

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happened. I had the file in zip folders, and I thought I had to unzip the files first to process them. It turns out that when unzipping through ADF, it stripped the quotation marks from my columns, and then one of the columns had an escape character in it. That escape character shifted everything over, and resulted in me losing nine columns.

But I did learn a bunch of things NOT to do, so it wasn't a total waste of time. Thanks for the answers!